# Overriding JasperServer's ACL mechanisim

Tags: authentication, authorization, acl, jasperserver

I'm trying to embed **JasperServer** into a web application and I like the look and feel of JasperServer's interface as is. I just want to override JasperServer's ACL engine and divert it so it will use my own application's instead.

For starters, if the user is already authenticated in the host web application, JasperServer shouldn't ask for it one more time. More over, whenever JasperServer is trying to decide whether to show or not some part of the interface, it should be the host application's ACL data to grant or deny the permission. The same goes for the list of reports one user can use.

Can someone please guide me to the right direction if and how this is possible?

Comment: Assuming you have knowledge of java/spring you can configure almost every part of the authentication/authorization with jasperserver. Have you read the jasperserver authentication cookbook https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-authentication-cookbook/v601/introduction